# pass a value from javascript to html and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i using hidden's input

```
<input type='hidden' name='bahan' id='bahan' />
```

then, i want pass a value from js. i have a function called `resultBtn()` i get the value from it, example string `var x='12,124';`
i want take the value from other input

```
<?php $i=0; foreach ($bahanx as $pin2){ 
  echo "<div class='input-group' style='width:175%'><label class='input-group-addon' style='width:100px'><input type='checkbox' name='bahan' aria-label='Checkbox for following text input' value='".$pin2->id_barang."' oninput='changeText(this,".$i.");' > ". $pin2->nama_barang ."</label><input type='text' class='form-control' aria-label='Text input with checkbox' name='banyak_bahan' value='0' disabled/></div><br/>";
  $i++;  }  ?>
```

at `resultBtn()` i make a formula from `bahanx` then the result is `x` variable.
this is my js

```
document.getElementsByName('bahan').value=x;
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('bahan')[0].value=x;`

Comment: ty bro, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)** method returns a collection of elements([NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)) so you need to retrieve element by index.

```
document.getElementsByName('bahan')[0].value = x;
//                           ------^^^------
```